# NSScrollview autolayout issue

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsscrollview

I have an `NSScrollview` which contains two views, 
lets call them `View A` and `View B` respectively,
now both of them can grow in height, i want that `View A` appears at the top
and `View B` at bottom and that when the height of the two combined is greater than the `NSScrollView` clip view i want to be able to scroll as usual

I just can't seem to get the AutoLayout constraints correct for this behaviour 
im using `Masonry` anyone has had the same issue/dificulty with `AutoLayout` and `NSSCrollView` and can point me in the right path ?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently experimented with shoehorning two table views into a single scroll view.
My set up had a scroll view with a clip view. Within that a custom view. Within that I have the two growing views. Constraints have the the custom view grow with the two child views.

One thing I noticed: If you set up your own scroll view, you need to create constraints to tie your view to the clip view it is in. I had to set up constraints to pin the my custom view to the top, left and right of the clip view. If I add a fourth constraint to pin the bottom to the clip view, the scroll view actually grows with my own content view.

Sample project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2381634/SO/GrowingViews.zip

Comment: Hi, thanks for nice project. How can we let two views stick to top? Currently those are stick to bottom of the scroll view.

Comment: You can #define AUTO_GROW 1. In IB, add a placeholder view at the bottom to grow with the scrollview.

Comment: If I do so, the red view is stretching.

Comment: The red view is acting as a filler / placeholder. Add a additional view with white background as placeholder.